# ERRO AO DESSERIALIZAR JSON com C#

Tags: c#, json

Estou obtendo erro **System.InvalidOperationException: 'O tipo 'projeto.classeCategorias' não é suportado para desserialização de uma matriz.'** ao desserializar JSON abaixo:

**Veja como estou obtendo o JSON no C#:**

```
var client = new RestClient('https://api.tiendanube.com/v1/1492214/categories');
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
request.AddHeader('User-Agent', 'XXXXXX');
request.AddHeader('Authentication', 'XXXXXX');
IRestResponse responseData = client.Execute(request);
```

**JSON (vem nesse formato ao fazer o GET):**

```
[\n    {\n        \"id\": 8369593,\n        \"parent\": 0,\n        \"subcategories\": [\n            8369664\n        ],\n        \"created_at\": \"2021-02-24T17:28:22+00:00\",\n        \"updated_at\": \"2021-02-24T17:28:22+00:00\",\n        \"name\": {\n            \"pt\": \"Livro\"\n        },\n        \"handle\": {\n            \"pt\": \"livro\"\n        },\n        \"description\": {\n            \"pt\": \"\"\n        },\n        \"seo_title\": {\n            \"pt\": \"\"\n        },\n        \"seo_description\": {\n            \"pt\": \"\"\n        }\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": 8369664,\n        \"parent\": 8369593,\n        \"subcategories\": [],\n        \"created_at\": \"2021-02-24T17:35:14+00:00\",\n        \"updated_at\": \"2021-02-24T17:35:14+00:00\",\n        \"name\": {\n            \"pt\": \"Administra\\u00e7\\u00e3o\"\n        },\n        \"handle\": {\n            \"pt\": \"administracao\"\n        },\n        \"description\": {\n            \"pt\": \"\"\n        },\n        \"seo_title\": {\n            \"pt\": \"\"\n        },\n        \"seo_description\": {\n            \"pt\": \"\"\n        }\n    }\n]
```

**Abaixo o comando para desserializar o JSON (é nele que ocorre o erro):**

```
var JsonConvert = new JavaScriptSerializer();
classeCategorias classeCategoria = JsonConvert.Deserialize<classeCategorias>(responseData.Content.ToString());
```

**Estou utilizando a classe abaixo (criada através do menu EDIT / PASTE ESPECIAL / PASTE JSON AS CLASSES no Visual Studio):**

```
public class classeCategorias
    {
         public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int parent { get; set; }
        public int?[] subcategories { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
        public Name name { get; set; }
        public Handle handle { get; set; }
        public Description description { get; set; }
        public Seo_Title seo_title { get; set; }
        public Seo_Description seo_description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Name
    {
        public string pt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Handle
    {
        public string pt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Description
    {
        public string pt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Seo_Title
    {
        public string pt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Seo_Description
    {
        public string pt { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: tenta usar um List:  `public List<Class1> Property1 { get; set; }`

Comment: Ocorre o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, obrigado a todos, consegui resolver (ajuda de outro fórum).
Segue para quem precisar:

```
var JsonConvert = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Class1> categorias = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<Class1>>(responseData.Content.ToString());
```